# UIStackView before iOS 9.0 in Xcode 7 beta 5

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uistackview

I'm using Xcode 7 beta 5, and I'm getting an error that says "UIStackView before iOS 9.0". I see that at least one other person has had this problem, but their solution isn't working for me. My deployment target is 9.0.

Here's a link to some helpful screenshots (since I guess I can't post pictures yet): https://docs.google.com/document/d/178kcpuzzeQM6lBAso4srStc0pnDL_2x1Z59_QevcKoc/edit?usp=sharing

Also, I've already erased and re-made the UI once, and didn't help. 
Any insight is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a open source project called [OAStackView](https://github.com/oarrabi/OAStackView).

With OAStackView, you can compatible with iOS7.

Hope this can help you.

Edit:

If the error still shows in the Interface Builder, try change the Project Deployment Target to 9.0

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But I guess my main question at this point is: What about my Main.storyboard causes the error? I just tried deleting all of my UI elements, and the error is still there. How? I've updated the document linked to in the question to include a screenshot of my current Main.storyboard.

Comment: See edit. This link may also helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31758808/uistackview-before-ios-9-0

Comment: Thank you! I ended up just copying my project to Xcode 6 and everything worked fine. Didn't try your edited answer.